# Tomcat: Custom form authenicator in a web application, not as a stand-alone JAR module. Possible?

Tags: tomcat, form-authentication, context.xml, tomcat-valve

Our web application requires custom form authentication with specific logic inside. The current form authenticator implementation requires the authenticator module, let's call it `custom.auth.jar`, to be present in `%CATALINA_HOME%/lib` before the web application starts. The web application uses that custom authenticator module using the following `context.xml` directive:

```xml
<Valve className="foo.bar.CustomAuth" characterEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

As far as I understand Tomcat requirements, this module, `custom.auth.jar`, must be present in Tomcat's `lib` directory before the web application starts, because the web application does not seem to require the authenticator code packaged with the web archive -- it always tries to find it in `%CATALINA_HOMA%/lib`. Otherwise the web application simply cannot start:

```
SEVERE: Parse error in context.xml for /webapp
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: foo.bar.CustomAuth
```

Due to the specifics of the authentication business logic and some protection, we were forced to introduce some kind of versioning of the authentication module, and check its version in the web application application listener -- if the web application finds an incompatible version of authentication module (not checking the JAR-file provided in the Tomcat's library directory -- we use reflection instead) -- it simply refuses to start reporting the compatibility error between the web application being tried to start and the authentication module. Again, an *existing* authenticator module must be specified in `context.xml`.

Despite it protects the incompatible versions, this gives some major difficulties: we cannot start another version of the same application in the same Tomcat instance, because these two applications require different versions of the authentication module. But there can be a single version in the Tomcat's `lib` directory.

My question is: is it possible to package the custom `FormAuthenticator` directly in the web application not requiring that single version of the `FormAuthenticator` to be loaded before the web application is being started? This would allow to start as many versions of the web application as we want and do not touch `%CATALINA_HOME%/lib` at all.

In other words: how can I make Tomcat to take the custom authenticator module from the web application, not from its home library directory? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Valve` classes cannot be loaded by a webapp class loader. Take a look at the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138396/custom-tomcat-valve-contained-in-web-app-war-file) question.

As a possible solution to the versioning issue, consider starting different Tomcat instances by overriding the CATLINA_BASE environment variable. Running with separate CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE is  documented in RUNNING.txt file which can be found in Tomcat distribution. I could also share a working example configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the link to the Q/A (this shares exactly the same idea as we have already done). For the second: so there is no way to have `host/app-v1` and `host/app-v2` running under the same Tomcat instance, right?

Comment: As long as you need to be able to put JARs with different versions of the authenticator valve, there's no way.
However, if the objective is to have them under the same hostname and port, the solution with different instances using their own CATALINA_BASE's plus a httpd front-end could work.

Comment: Just the final remark and another reason of why "an authenticator could be a part of a web app" is useful: you usually might want to access these classes only from that web application, and do not share these classes among other web applications. But anyway, thanks again for the clarification.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv I do agree, but it turns out that Valves have to have some limitations to be able to address so many different applications during the request processing.