# How to capture Response status Tomcat JaasRealm with custom Login Module

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, jaas

I am using Tomcat CMA using JaasRealm with custom login module. In this I am overriding the `boolean LoginModule#login()` method. Now, whenever a request enters the webapplication context, first it is being authenticated by this login method. As, this login method has `boolean` return type

```
  @Override
    public boolean login() throws LoginException {

        Callback[] callbacks = new Callback[2];
```

so if returning value is `true` then it proceeds to complete the further request and if returning value is `false` then it returns `401 Status`. There are some cases where cases where I want to return other then 401 status when returning value is false. But it seems that it is not possible to me. Any idea how can I send back my modified status in response when loginModule returns false.

Comment: what tomcat version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

You can't influence the response neither in the login modules, nor in the JAASRealm, these classes just creates a Principal if the authentication was successful, or null otherwise, the JAASRealm on top of that swallow every exception.

So, in order to do that, you should

- extend the JAASRealm, and override the authenticate and throw the AccountExpiredException/FailedLoginException/etc. as wrapped unchecked exception (custom RuntimeException)
- extend the DigestAuthenticator class and override the doAuthenticate (or copy the whole source, this will definitely work), catch your custom RuntimeExceptions there and use response.sendError() to set the response code to what you want
- configure the whole thing as usual, using your custom JAASRealm class, and the CustomDigestAuthenticator should be [registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447146/tomcat-custom-form-authenicator-in-a-web-application-not-as-a-stand-alone-jar) (I don't know that it is possible to do it in a less global way)

A similar thread can be found [here](https://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/0767xxccq4/is-it-possible-to-introduce-new-authentication-method-without-modifying-tomcat)